# undesirable data stored in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, amazon-web-services, mysqli

i have created **two aws instances** in both of which i am storing data in mysql database by taking input from web server while in one of which i am taking userid and password as input while on the other its just a long string while in username and password the data gets stored as required but in the comment storing database it just stored '|-|' as output on the database when the string size was put to *5000* while when put to *10* it stores '_' replacing everything that my client(on test purpose i am only the client) has sent please help me to resolve this issue and i cant debug the whole thing as i am doing th esame thing with my other instance and its working fine so help will be appreciated

[this image shows what the database of my two instances are storing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slngy.jpg)